# Sprout SEO: Redirect to Separate Domain

Tags: craft3, plugin-sproutseo

We just migrated a site from Craft 2 to Craft 3 and I'm running into an issue with some redirects we used to have setup in Sprout SEO.

Our site runs a Craft CMS backend with a Nuxt frontend along with a 3rd vanity URL. We used to have Sprout SEO setup in a way that all requests to the vanity URL would get redirected to the main domain running on Nuxt. However, it seems that Sprout now appends the Base URL to the redirect along with using the 'Sites' functionality in Craft 3, which has effectively broken the redirects.

So I guess my question comes down to this: is there a good way in Sprout to redirect from one domain to another like was possible in the Craft 2 instance? And if not, is there a different way to do so within Craft? We want to be able to give our content team the ability to add redirects rather than hardcoding them in the nginx config.

Comment: This might not be possible at the moment but it's a use case on our list that we'd like to support. To make sure I understand, do you have your Vanity URL setup as a Site in Craft? And the Content Editor would login to the Site for the Vanity URL which lets them setup redirects to the primary Site?

Comment: Hey @BenParizek ideally we would be able to setup the redirect without the added site in Craft. We're running Craft as a headless CMS that then serves JSON information to a Nuxt frontend, so there's not really a need for Craft to have multiple sites set up as that might get confusing for the user.  If it's helpful to know, we have 3 separate URLs right now. A CMS URL, a vanity URL, and our main URL. The main URL hits the Nuxt server directly while the vanity and CMS URLs go to Craft. The idea being that Craft can be used to handle the redirect from vanity to main.

Comment: Ok, understood. Looks like we'll have to make it possible to match incoming absolute URLs from a given site or redirect to absolute URLs from a secondary site. I've opened a ticket on the issue at the link below if you'd like to add any more details and will update this thread when we have a solution: https://github.com/barrelstrength/craft-sprout-seo/issues/120